# Decide whether the series is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{a}{n}\right),\: a\in \mathbb{R}$$

I'm afraid I cannot use the alternating series test since $\sin(n)$ is not a decreasing sequence. Which test should I use instead?

Comment: Using the [Prosthaphaeresis Reverse Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)

$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$


with $x=\frac{a}{n+1}$ and $y=\frac{a}n$ reveals for $n\ge 1$

$$\sin\left(\frac{a}{n+1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{a}n\right)=-2\sin\left(\frac{a}{2n(n+1)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)a}{2n(n+1)}\right)<0$$

when $n>\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2a}{\pi}}-1\right)$.

Comment: Note that we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(a/n)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac an+\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sin(a/n)-\frac an\right)$$

The first series is the divergent harmonic series.  The second series converges absolutely since $\sin(a/n)-\frac an=O(1/n^3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ For sufficiently large $n,$ $\left | \sin \left (\frac a n \right ) \right |$ definitely decreases and converges to $0$. So use Leibnitz test for alternating series to complete. Since convergence or divergence of a series does not depend on finitely many terms of it you are through.

Observe that if $a=0$ the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin \left ( {\frac a n} \right )$ is absolutely convergent and hence convergent as well.

Now for $a \neq 0$ we have $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {\sin \left (\frac a n \right )} {\frac 1 n} = a \neq 0.$ Hence by the limit form of the comparison test it follows that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin \left ({\frac a n} \right )$ is not absolutely convergent (Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 n$ is divergent) though it is convergent. Therefore the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin \left ( {\frac a n} \right )$ is conditionally convergent for $a \neq 0.$

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea why $sin(a/n)$ converges to 0, but why does it decrease? Intuitively, I thought it should oscillate around zero but not thoroughly decrease.

Comment: As $n \rightarrow \infty,$ then the sequence $\{ \frac a n \}$ converges to zero. Since sine function is continuous so by the sequential criterion for continuous functions we have the sequence $\{\sin \left ( \frac a n \right ) \}$ should converge to $\sin 0$ which is $0.$

Comment: I am asking why should it decrease "for sufficiently large n" though

Comment: For sufficiently large values of $n$ we may bring $\frac a n \in \left (0, \frac \pi 2 \right)$ if $a>0$ in which case $\sin \left ( \frac a n \right )$ decreases. Similarly if $a<0$ then we may bring $\frac a n \in \left ( -\frac \pi 2,0 \right).$  In which case $-\sin \left (\frac a n \right)$ decreases.

Comment: And here is the "sufficiently large $n$."  Using the [Prosthaphaeresis Reverse Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$


with $x=\frac{a}{n+1}$ and $y=\frac{a}n$ reveals for $a\ge 0$ and $n\ge 1$

$$\sin\left(\frac{a}{n+1}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{a}n\right)=-2\sin\left(\frac{a}{2n(n+1)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(2n+1)a}{2n(n+1)}\right)<0$$when $n>\frac12\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2a}{\pi}}-1\right)$.

Comment: Note that we can write

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(a/n)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac an+\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sin(a/n)-\frac an\right)$$

The first series is the divergent harmonic series.  The second series converges absolutely since $\sin(a/n)-\frac an=O(1/n^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute the limit of $n\sin\frac{a}{n}$. After computing this limit, what does it tell you about the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\frac{a}{n}$?